# Is there a way to connect a model object with another object?

Tags: django, django-models, model, foreign-keys, relationship

So i have a problem where I have two models; ORDER and ORDERITEM, as seen before

```
    class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        #post = models.ForeignKey('OrderItem', related_name='oi', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
        transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcode', blank=True)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.transaction_id)
    
    class OrderItem(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.post.title
```

This is how it works, when a user makes an order it goes to the orderitem, when its order is completed, it goes to Order model, now, i want to be able to get the Post the user purchased from Order (not Orderitem) Model, i can get it from OrderItem, because presently with the code abov Order models does not show the particular post purchased, it just shows a list of all the posts. I really need to get the Post purchased from Order because im building a notification system using signals and it has to be from Order (which is created when the user FINISHES the process of making an order). I hope you get me, any follow up questions, I'd be glad to response. So even if i can get a way to get the post purchased from OrderItem to Order. Id be glad.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow relationship "backwards". See [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) section in Django's model field reference documentation.